# Camel activeMQ Topic Publish Subscribe

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

Given the following route in camel.

```
.to("activemq:queue:REQUEST_QUEUE")
.to("activemq:topic:UPDATE_TOPIC_NAME");
```

I'm getting a timeout exception if I don't let any route listen to my topic.

Now I don't really want anyone to listen to this topic. I just want to deliver it to the topic and move on (Publish subscribe).

How can I do this with Apache Camel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set ExchangePattern.InOnly like:

```
.to("activemq:queue:REQUEST_QUEUE")
.to(ExchangePattern.InOnly, "activemq:topic:UPDATE_TOPIC_NAME");
```

For more information see the [Camel JMS](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) documentation.